# List filtered selection in ListBox

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to list only filtred selections in a ListBox, everything works except I am not sure what to load into the ListBox. This my code

```
Private Sub btnRechercher_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lstMoyens.Clear

    Sheets("TEST1").Select
    Range("Tableau4[[#Headers],[Famille]]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tableau4").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=" & cbFamille.SelText, Operator:=xlAnd

    Range("B1:C1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection.Rows
        lstMoyens.AddItem (r.Cells(3) & " : " & r.Cells(4))
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Change `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select` to `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select` to select only the visible

Comment: @Adach1979, short but spot on. I think you should put it as an answer. I'll vote it up at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you

```
Private Sub btnRechercher_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    lstMoyens.Clear

    Sheets("TEST1").Select
    Range("Tableau4[[#Headers],[Famille]]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tableau4").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="=" & cbFamille.SelText, Operator:=xlAnd

    Range("B1:C1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection.Rows
        lstMoyens.AddItem (r.Cells(3) & " : " & r.Cells(4))
    Next r
End Sub
```